# Error with Object mapper reading JSON from file

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to get to grips with Jackson JSON parser and have found a good tutorial that explains marshalling and unmarshalling. The tutorial is here

http://java.dzone.com/tips/json-processing-using-jackson

Now I have entered all the code, and I have set up the getters and setters in the username and user class. Now I want to be able to create a User Object from the JSON file as it shows in the tutorial i.e.

```
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("/Users/adam/Documents/JSON/user.json"), User.class);
```

However this returns an error

> Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "firstName" (Class UserName), not marked as ignorable
>    at [Source: /Users/adam/Documents/JSON/JSON.json; line: 1, column: 40] (through reference chain: User["userName"]->UserName["firstName"])

I can create an object from user if I use the String instead like so

```
String userDataJSON = "{\"userId\":\"100\",\"userName\":{\"firstname\":\"K\",\"middlename\":\"Siva\",\"lastname\":\"Prasad\"},\"dob\":1300878089906}";

User user = mapper.readValue(userDataJSON, User.class);
```

But If I try

```
 JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser(new File(
        "/Users/adam/Documents/JSON/user.json"));

    User user = mapper.readValue(jParser, User.class);
```

I get the error I showed above.

But same thing. Would anytime be able to tell me what I am doing wrong?? Thanks in advance

The JSON in the file is

> {
>      "userId":"1",
>      "userName":{
>         "firstName":"Katamreddy",
>         "middleName":"Siva",
>         "lastName":"PrasadReddy"
>      },
>      "dob":1331113476212
>   }

Comment: One additional tip: instead of creating JsonFactory, parser, just use `ObjectMapper` directly; that simplifies your code a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"firstName" != "firstname"

Check the case of your property.

Comment: OMG!!!! I can't believe I missed that, I copied and pasted the JSON from the output file, and assumed the casing the same. Thanks for pointing it out!!